# MZFormSheetController Assertion failure

Tags: ios, uialertview

I'm using Custom AlertView [MZFromSheetController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController), but it gives me the following Exception

```
*** Assertion failure in -[MZFormSheetController presentAnimated:completionHandler:], /Users/dt4it/Documents/SucessQuotes11/SucessQuotes/MZFormSheetController.m:418
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to begin a form sheet transition from to while a transition is already in progress. Wait for didPresentCompletionHandler/didDismissCompletionHandler to know the current transition has completed'
```

Could anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you aren't calling the presentation method multiple times, I just hit this exact issue and found that the code was being called 4 times. Reducing it down to 1 (as it should be) fixed up the Assertion failure Exception.